# EF Core update-database System.Globalization.CultureNotFoundException:

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-8.0

When I execute `update-database` in package manager console to create a database, I get an error:

PM> update-database
Build started...
Build succeeded.
System.Globalization.CultureNotFoundException: Only the invariant culture is supported in globalization-invariant mode. See https://aka.ms/GlobalizationInvariantMode for more information. (Parameter 'name')
en-us is an invalid culture identifier.
at System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(String name)
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, SqlConnectionOverrides overrides) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open(SqlConnectionOverrides overrides) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerConnection.OpenDbConnection(Boolean errorsExpected) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternal(Boolean errorsExpected) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(Boolean errorsExpected) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.<>c__DisplayClass18_0.<Exists>b__0(DateTime giveUp) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass12_0`2.b__0(DbContext _, TState s)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.Execute[TState,TResult](IExecutionStrategy strategy, TState state, Func`2 operation, Func`2 verifySucceeded)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.Exists(Boolean retryOnNotExists)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.Exists()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.Exists()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Only the invariant culture is supported in globalization-invariant mode. See https://aka.ms/GlobalizationInvariantMode for more information. (Parameter 'name')
en-us is an invalid culture identifier.
PM>

I use Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Preview
Version 17.8.0 Preview 1.0 |
Asp.net core Web API |
EF Core 7.0.11

My context:

```cs
using Componente.Pessoa;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Diagnostics;

public class APIContext : DbContext, IPessoaContext
{
    public DbSet<Pessoa> dbPessoas { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Cliente> dbClientes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Endereco> dbEnderecos { get; set; }

    public IConfiguration _configuration;

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=OmnesProducao;;Integrated Security=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;User Id=sa;Password=pass;", builder =>
        {
        });
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);

    }

    
    public APIContext()
    {
        
    }

    public APIContext(DbContextOptions<APIContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }



    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        PessoaContext.CarregaModel(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

My Program.cs

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Globalization.Invariant", true);

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Comment: Your Program file doesn't contain any Entity Framework code, so I'm not sure how you're getting the EF error you say you're getting. Try making a [mre].

Comment: DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.—copy or type the text into the question. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: For some reason your app is running in [globalization invariant mode](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/docs/design/features/globalization-invariant-mode.md) which is not detected by [`Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/blob/c1984b822f8d31794cd8c85245cc6d7bd1059526/src/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient/netcore/src/Microsoft/Data/SqlClient/SqlConnection.cs#L1870). You can try adding `AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Globalization.Invariant", true);` to the start of your app but I wounder why it considers to be in this mode - add info about you env and [mre].

Comment: @GuruStron thx for response, i try use this code but dont work, i make a default api aspnet core api, reference EF core, create map and context to make DB, i dont know if i need put any config, i put in appsetting.json and launchSettings  Invariant = true, but no work too

Comment: @MaiconCardozo please read my comment and provided comments carefully.

Comment: Also ideally - provide the [mre] and environment description to reproduce.

Comment: @GuruStron sry, i edit question and write my code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

your project configured to use invariant globalization

check in your project file for this property

```
{
  "runtimeOptions": {
     "configProperties": {
        "System.Globalization.Invariant": true
     }
  }
}
```

and set it to `False`

your project file property most be like this

```
{
  "runtimeOptions": {
     "configProperties": {
        "System.Globalization.Invariant": false
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I update for EF8 and WebAPI (at least with the project created in Visual Studio 2022).
You must click on the project name and make the following change.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
  <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  <InvariantGlobalization>true</InvariantGlobalization>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Set InvariantGlobalization to false

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
  <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  <InvariantGlobalization>false</InvariantGlobalization>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Thank you. This was killing me and nearly impossible to find a simple answer to.